# Glut and cuda stall for 100ms every second

Tags: opengl, cuda, glut, freeglut, nsight

I am working on a project that involves cuda and freeglut and I am trying to get every bit of juice out of it as possible.

I have a loop that does some compute and then draw. I noticed from the nsight trace that every second there is about 100 to 200 ms that it appears nothing is being done with. This is just plain unacceptable. I would ideally like to eliminate this stall as it is causing me to only go 80%-90% as fast as I could be.

The stall does not happen right on the dot at the beginning of the second but it happens at very regular intervals.

My processing loop looks something like this

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

kernel_call_1( ... , stream0);

if(T != 0) cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, event0, 0);
     cudaMemcpyAsync( ... ,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,stream1);


kernel_call_2( ... , stream0);
cudaEventRecord(event0, stream0);


drawGL( ... );
```

The OpenGL is done on a separate card from the CUDA, the output of CUDA is brought onto the host with that memcpy and the pushed to OpenGL with a glTexSubImage3D.

Does CUDA or OpenGL or FreeGLUT do anything behind my back that might account for the stall?

EDIT:
Something else I noticed, NSight makes a distinction between cpu and gpu frames. If I look at the cpu frames, they seem to slowly fallout of sync with the gpu. This happens up until the stall in which case a single cpu frame runs long but the gpu frames keep going at the same speed and it pulls them back in sync. Is OpenGL doing a synchronization behind my back and is there some way to control this behavior?

EDIT: 
Here is a screen shot of NSight trace.
[image: NSight Trace]

Comment: I had a similar experience, nervertheless, I was only running on 1 GPU. I realized that since the kernel call and openGL calls are async, the kernel calls were "catching up", i.e.: the GPU was running 2 kernel launches one after another before he could make a context switch to OpenGL. In my case, it helped to move the cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the CUDA calls and before the drawGL() call.

Comment: That is not a suitable solution, currently the CUDA and the OpenGL are running concurrently(as they are on different GPUs). A devsync between the the CUDA and the OpenGL pushes the OpenGL out from underneath the CUDA and they run one after the other.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you might want to draw the geometry that is independent from your CUDA results in parallel with your CUDA computations. As soon as your CUDA finishes you can draw your CUDA dependent geometry and in this case, you would need the cudaDeviceSynchronize(). Also notice how your GPU frames lag behind your CPU frames, is this really intentional? And on a sidenote, you might also take glFinish() into consideration.

Comment: No the lag of the cpu frames is not intentional and might be the source of the stall.

Comment: Correction, it is not the cpu frames that are lagging behind but the gpu frames that are.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am chasing the same stalling issue.

Comment: OpenGL trace has a single buffer for GPU workload events (draw calls, command buffers, transfers, and frames). When this fills up the records are dumped causing stall. Please note how the CPU frame exceeds the GPU frame end time. If you disable OpenGL trace I think the stall will disappear. We are hoping to significantly reduce graphics trace overhead in the Nsight version after 4.0.

Comment: @GregSmith: Would you mind adding a short answer to that effect so we can get this off the unanswered question list?

Answer (score 1):

According to an NVIDIA employee, at the time the question was asked (2014), the following was the case:

> OpenGL trace has a single buffer for GPU workload events (draw calls,
> command buffers, transfers, and frames). When this fills up the
> records are dumped causing stall. Please note how the CPU frame
> exceeds the GPU frame end time. If you disable OpenGL trace I think
> the stall will disappear. We are hoping to significantly reduce
> graphics trace overhead in the Nsight version after 4.0.

So the likely solution is to disable OpenGL trace in Nsight.

[This answer added as a community wiki entry to preserve an answer-in-comments and get the question off the unanswered queue. Feel free to vote and edit as required].